# Pass parameters to node using gtest

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, gtest, ros2-launch

I am trying to create some tests for a package using the gtest suite. Everything works fine, up to the point when I need to pass the test node some parameters. I can't manage to make the node initialize such parameters with the provided values, hence when I try to access them the node exits.

---

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (jammy) and ROS2 Humble. My setup is as follows:

```
example_test/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── example_test
│       └── my_node.hpp
├── launch
│   └── launch_file.py
├── LICENSE
├── package.xml
├── src
│   ├── my_node.cpp
│   └── my_node_main.cpp
└── test
    ├── launch_file.py
    └── test.cpp
```

**example_test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(example_test)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    include
    )

add_executable(my_node_exec src/my_node.cpp src/my_node_main.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_node_exec PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    )
ament_target_dependencies(my_node_exec rclcpp)

install(TARGETS
    my_node_exec
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(
    DIRECTORY launch
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
    #    find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
    #    ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()

    find_package(ament_cmake_gtest)
    ament_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_test src/my_node.cpp test/test.cpp)
    ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_test rclcpp)

    find_package(launch_testing_ament_cmake REQUIRED)
    add_launch_test(test/launch_file.py)

    install(TARGETS
        ${PROJECT_NAME}_test
        DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

endif()

ament_package()
```

**example_test/package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
    <name>example_test</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>TODO: Package description</description>
    <maintainer email="todo@todo.todo">todo</maintainer>
    <license>Apache-2.0</license>

    <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

    <depend>rclcpp</depend>

    <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>
    <test_depend>launch_testing_ament_cmake</test_depend>

    <export>
        <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
    </export>
</package>
```

## Launch

The following launch file works fine

**example_test/launch/launch_file.py**

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='example_test',
            namespace='my_node_namespace',
            executable='my_node_exec',
            name='my_node_name',
            parameters=[{'int_param': 42}]
            ),
        ])
```

If I try to build and launch everything with the following command

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && colcon build && source install/local_setup.bash && ros2 launch example_test launch_file.py
```

the output is

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [my_node_exec-1]: process started with pid [55721]
[my_node_exec-1] [INFO] [1711715840.155603117] [my_node_namespace.my_node_name]: int_param: 42
[INFO] [my_node_exec-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 55721]
```

Hence it is able to load the `int_param` parameter with a value of 42 as expected.

## Test

For testing, I use the following launch file

```
import launch
import launch_ros
import launch_testing

from launch.actions import (LogInfo, RegisterEventHandler)
from launch.event_handlers import (OnShutdown)
from launch.substitutions import (LocalSubstitution)

import pytest
import unittest

PACKAGE_NAME = "example_test"

def create_test_node():
    test_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package = PACKAGE_NAME,
            namespace = 'my_node_test_namespace',
            executable = PACKAGE_NAME + "_test",
            name = 'my_node_test_name',
            parameters=[{'int_param': 52}]
            )
    return test_node

@pytest.mark.rostest
def generate_test_description():
    test_node = create_test_node()
    context = {"test_node": test_node}
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        test_node,
        launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest(),
        ]), context
```

#### Case 1

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && colcon build && source install/local_setup.bash && colcon test && colcon test-result --verbose
```

I obtain

```
Starting >>> example_test                                                                                                                                                                     
Finished <<< example_test [0.34s]                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                              
Summary: 1 package finished [0.66s]                                                                                                                                                           
Starting >>> example_test                                                                                                                                                                     
--- stderr: example_test                                                                                                                                                                      
Errors while running CTest                                                                                                                                                                    
Output from these tests are in: ~/ros2_examples/build/example_test/Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log
Use "--rerun-failed --output-on-failure" to re-run the failed cases verbosely.
---
Finished <<< example_test [0.86s]       [ with test failures ]

Summary: 1 package finished [1.22s]
  1 package had stderr output: example_test
  1 package had test failures: example_test
build/example_test/Testing/20240329-1245/Test.xml: 2 tests, 0 errors, 1 failure, 0 skipped
- example_test_test
  <<< failure message
    -- run_test.py: invoking following command in '~/ros2_examples/build/example_test':
     - ~/ros2_examples/build/example_test/example_test_test --gtest_output=xml:~/ros2_examples/build/example_test/test_results/example_test/example_test_test.gtest.xml
    [==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
    [----------] Global test environment set-up.
    [----------] 2 tests from MyNodeTest
    [ RUN      ] MyNodeTest.CompilationTestSuccess
    [       OK ] MyNodeTest.CompilationTestSuccess (0 ms)
    [ RUN      ] MyNodeTest.NodeInit
    unknown file: Failure
    C++ exception with description "parameter 'int_param' is not initialized" thrown in the test body.
    [  FAILED  ] MyNodeTest.NodeInit (20 ms)
    [----------] 2 tests from MyNodeTest (20 ms total)
     
    [----------] Global test environment tear-down
    [==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (20 ms total)
    [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
    [  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
    [  FAILED  ] MyNodeTest.NodeInit
     
     1 FAILED TEST
    -- run_test.py: return code 1
    -- run_test.py: inject classname prefix into gtest result file '~/ros2_examples/build/example_test/test_results/example_test/example_test_test.gtest.xml'
    -- run_test.py: verify result file '~/ros2_examples/build/example_test/test_results/example_test/example_test_test.gtest.xml'
    >>>
build/example_test/test_results/example_test/example_test_test.gtest.xml: 2 tests, 0 errors, 1 failure, 0 skipped
- example_test.MyNodeTest NodeInit
  <<< failure message
    unknown file
    C++ exception with description "parameter 'int_param' is not initialized" thrown in the test body.
  >>>

Summary: 4 tests, 0 errors, 2 failures, 0 skipped
```

#### Case 2

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash && colcon build && source install/local_setup.bash && launch_test example_test/test/launch_file.py
```

and its (not very detailed) output is

```
Starting >>> example_test
Finished <<< example_test [0.35s]                     

Summary: 1 package finished [0.70s]
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below [...]
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
[INFO] [example_test_test-1]: process started with pid [57078]
[INFO] [example_test_test-1]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[example_test_test-1]
[ERROR] [example_test_test-1]: process has died [pid 57078, exit code -2, cmd '~/ros2_examples/install/example_test/lib/example_test/example_test_test --ros-args -r __node:=my_node_test_name --params-file /tmp/launch_params_fwmchc36'].

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

and the content of the `/tmp/launch_params_fwmchc36` file is

```
/**:
  ros__parameters:
    int_param: 52
```

which should be correctly read from the node.

---

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to pass a list of arguments to a node also while testing?

**NOTE**: In this example I have only used one node with a single parameter, but I typically have a common config file with all the parameters for all the node. Also in this case, using the "standard" launch approach (i.e., not testing) I am able to pass the arguments to the node, but I can't manage to do it in testing.